# Rails: no block given (yield)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting in my rails app this error `no block given (yield)` and this is referred to this line in my file `elements = Element.where(study_version_id: self.id).find_each` I'm trying to export to an XML file some data which is generated in my app. When I try to export I have that error and I would like some help to resolve it.

The entire code related:

```
def to_xml
    # Build the document and the header elements
    odm_document = Odm.new("ODM-#{self.id}", "Assero", "Tourmalet", Version::VERSION)
    odm = odm_document.root
    study = odm.add_study("S-#{self.id}")
    global_variables = study.add_global_variables()
    global_variables.add_study_name("#{self.name}")
    global_variables.add_study_description("#{self.description}")
    global_variables.add_protocol_name("#{self.protocol_name}")
    metadata_version = study.add_metadata_version("MDV-#{self.id}", "Metadata for #{self.description}", "Study export.")
    protocol = metadata_version.add_protocol()
    # Get the set of visits, forms and elements.
    visits = Visit.where(study_version_id: self.id).order(ordinal: :asc)
    forms = Form.where(study_version_id: self.id).order(ordinal: :asc)
    elements = Element.where(study_version_id: self.id).find_each
    # Build the Protocol element.
    visits.each do |visit|
      protocol.add_study_event_ref("SE-#{visit.ordinal}", "#{visit.ordinal}", "Yes", "")
    end
    # Build the StudyEventDef elements
    visits.each do |visit|
      study_event_def = metadata_version.add_study_event_def("SE-#{visit.ordinal}", "#{visit.long_name}", "No", "Scheduled", "")
      elements = Element.where(study_version_id: self.id, visit_id: visit.id).find_each
      elements.each do |element|
        #ConsoleLogger.log(C_CLASS_NAME, "to_xml", "Element=#{element.to_json}")
        form = Form.find(element.form_id)
        study_event_def.add_form_ref("#{form.form_id}", "#{form.ordinal}", "Yes", "")
      end
    end
    # Now the remainder of the metadata
    forms.each do |form|
      form_json = Mdr.form_to_hash(form.form_id, form.form_namespace)
      #ConsoleLogger.log(C_CLASS_NAME, "to_xml", "JSON=#{form_json}")
      xml_node(form_json, metadata_version, nil)
    end
    return odm_document.to_xml
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to assign the query results to a local variable `elements` if you are using `find_each`.  Instead use a block (`do |element| ... end`)

```
Element.where(study_version_id: self.id, visit_id: visit.id).find_each do |element|
  #ConsoleLogger.log(C_CLASS_NAME, "to_xml", "Element=#{element.to_json}")
  form = Form.find(element.form_id)
  study_event_def.add_form_ref("#{form.form_id}", "#{form.ordinal}", "Yes", "")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick solvation is replace `find_each` with `all`. It will work if you have small database (I think it's your case)

`find_each` is used for optimization. It returns you not all records at once, but sets of records (1000 by default). If you have 1.000.000 record you will get `our of memory` exception in case trying to load it all at once.

You can rewrite your code with `find_each` usage as:

```
Element.where(study_version_id: self.id, visit_id: visit.id).find_each do |elements|
  elements.each do |element|
    #ConsoleLogger.log(C_CLASS_NAME, "to_xml", "Element=#{element.to_json}")
    form = Form.find(element.form_id)
    study_event_def.add_form_ref("#{form.form_id}", "#{form.ordinal}", "Yes", "")
  end
end
```

But I am 90% sure you should just go with:

```
elements = Element.where(study_version_id: self.id, visit_id: visit.id).all
elements.each do |element|
  #ConsoleLogger.log(C_CLASS_NAME, "to_xml", "Element=#{element.to_json}")
  form = Form.find(element.form_id)
  study_event_def.add_form_ref("#{form.form_id}", "#{form.ordinal}", "Yes", "")
end
```